# Should I create font icons or use images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, fonts, icon, svg

[image: psd print screen]

I applied for a frontend web developer job. They sent me PSD files and told me to create a one page website and send to them for review. On this image you can see just the header part. I am wondering if I should save these icons (logo, alert bell, nav link images..) as PNG images (in Photoshop select layer and then Save for Web), or should I create font icons out of these in Illustrator?

I am not good at Photoshop and Illustrator so I don't know what I should do. They told me not to use Fontello or similar font icons because they are not used in design.

If I need to convert the icons to SVG, can you leave a link with a tutorial?

Comment: Without seeing how the icons were provided to you, it's kinda hard to say what you should do in this situation. I'm also not sure if people will be into answering this question. The company is testing your ability to do the job, not our ability.

Comment: I agree with @Joonas. Things like this come up all the time, and its part of the front-end developers job.

Comment: I hate to be _that_ guy and I know the others have said this, but if you're asking us to help you with such a simple front-end task, I think you might be punching a bit above your weight here.  "Fake it, 'till you make it" can only get you so far and the fact that you're asking some pretty easy stuff, just to get your foot in the door, does not bode well for any future you might have at that company.

Answer (score 1):

> They told me not to use Fontello or similar font icons because they are not used in design.

There's your answer. They specifically told you not to use font icons—so don't use font icons.

> ...or should I create font icons out of these in Illustrator?

You can't just create a font in Illustrator. You export your vectors from Illustrator and either use a service such as Fontello or you use a font editor to create the font. I believe there are plugins for Illustrator that allow you to export fonts, but it's not something that you can do with Illustrator alone and it's not a simple process.

Creating icon fonts out of large icon sets is great, but the amount of effort it takes means it is unlikely to be worth it for 4 or 5 icons.

Export your icons as transparent PNGs or possibly SVGs.